# How to display enum list as a dropwdown from Controller to View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Class which has a enum property which I want to display as a dropdown for User to select from the available options.

Following is my Model Class:

```
public class DailyTask
{   
    
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Status))]
    public string Status { get; set; }

            
}

public enum Status
{
    Completed,
    InProgress,
    ToDo,
    Blocker
}
```

Following is the Controller Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult AddDsr()
        {
            
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                var uName = User.Identity.Name;
                User dto = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == uName).FirstOrDefault();
                var id = dto.UserId;
                DailyTask dailyTask = new DailyTask();

var enumData = from DailyTask e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))
                               select new
                               {
                                   Name = e.ToString()
                               };

                ViewBag.EnumList = new SelectList(enumData, "Name");
                // This is only for show by default one row for insert data to the database
                List<DailyTask> ci = new List<DailyTask>
                {
                    new DailyTask { Project = "", Task = "", Status = ViewBag.EnumList, UserId = id, Email= uName,Date=DateTime.Today } };
                return View(ci);
            }
```

Following is the View:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {


            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in Model)
            {
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Project,new { @required="required"})</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Task, new { @required = "required" })</td><td></td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("Status", ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].UserId, new { @class = "id", @type = "hidden" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Email,new { @class="email",@type="hidden"})</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Date, new { @type="hidden"})</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                @if (j > 0)
                {
                    //<a href="#" class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</a>
                    <button class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</button>
                }
                </td>
        </tr>
                j++;
            }
```

So, in the above View currently there is no dropdown, instead a text field. I want to display the dropdown there instead like as follow:
Select
Completed
InProgress

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f1047f/bind-enum-to-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: @YongShun tried the above shared solution but no success :(

Comment: No success is not a good description to your current issue in this community. What is not working, get an error/exception message?

Comment: Appreciate your response. Still looking at the issue. Will try more options to resolve this.

Comment: @YongShun please see the above code , updated with the fresh steps but getting an error a following: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'string'

Comment: Your property is a `String` - it needs to be the same type as the enum...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your current code:

1. To show the option label for the enum text like: Completed, In Progress, etc, you should use the `Enum.GetNames` method.

```cs
var enumData = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status))
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Name = x.ToString()
                    });
```

2. You should specify the property name used to show as the option label. Optionally, you can specify the default selected option in the forth argument.

```cs
ViewBag.EnumList = new SelectList(enumData, "Name", "Name", Status.Completed.ToString());
```

3. As your current error, you should assign a value with `string` but not `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList` type to the `Status`.

```cs
List<DailyTask> ci = new List<DailyTask>
{
    new DailyTask { Status = Status.Completed.ToString() }
};
```

4. Optionally, you can use the `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop as you are iterating element by index.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Model.Count; j++)
    {
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                    
            ...

            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model[j].Status, ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)</td>

            ...         
        </tr>
    }
}
```

[MVC Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PNMKru)

Comment: Thank you this worked for and was able to connect the missing link. However a bit of challenege, I have a jquery which dynamically adds input fields, but now it does not work since I have added the Select dropdown. Where is that I am stuck now with this.

Comment: Would be great to create a new question, provide the context and minimal code for your new issue. As the answer written is based on the question.

Comment: Thank you @Yong Shun have created a new question for the same.